# The best order to choose elements in the random array to maximize output?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

We have an array as input to production.

`R = [5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9]`

If `i`th input is chosen the output is sum of `i`th element, the max element whose index is less than `i` and the min element whose index is greater than `i`.

For example if I take 8, output would be 8+5+3=16.

Selected items cannot be selected again. So, if I select 8 the next array for next selection would look like `R = [5, 2, 3, 6, 9]`

What is the order to choose all inputs with maximum output in total? If possible, please send dynamic programming solutions.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"the max element that is on the left of i and the min element that is on the right side of i"* -- where do min and max enter into this?  In your example it is just a sum of the three elements R[i] + R[i-1] + R[i+1].

Comment: It just happens to be i-1 and i+1. For example if we take 6, it would be 6+8+9=23.

Comment: What happens if we pick the leftmost or rightmost element? Is there an example where the optimal strategy isn't simply to choose the second element from the right repeatedly?

Comment: Array is in arbitrary order. If I want to take 2, output will be 2 + 5 + 3=10. Because 5 is the maximum element whose index is smaller than i and 3 is the minimum element whose index is greater than i.

Comment: I don't get it: if you're repeatedly taking elements, then won't the final total just be the sum of all elements in the array?

Comment: @bymafmaf Oh, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @ruakh No, because you only eliminate one element, but sum three of them, so deciding which items *not* to pick is important, as they will remain in the array for longer and can be included in the final sum multiple times.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, choosing the smallest value each time might be optimal. I'm interested to see a counter-example proving this strategy incorrect. Even if it's not optimal in every case, it might be optimal often enough to be an acceptable approximate solution.

Comment: Does the array have duplicate entries?  Do you mean "So, if I select 8 the next array for next selection ..."  By the way, "If possible, please send dynamic programming solutions" makes it sound like you want us to do your homework for you.  What progress have you made so far?

Comment: @cdhowie Counterexample: [200, 1, 2, 3, 201, 202]. Clearly taking 3, then 2, then 1 would yield larger sums than taking 1, then 2, then 3.

Comment: @cdhowie R=[1,2,3,4,5] If we always choose the min output would be 3+5+7+9+5=30 But if we choose in order 1,3,2,4,0 output would be 6+12+9+6+1=34. So, strategy you provided doesn't always yield an optimal solution.

Comment: @MarkBailey Derp. Somewhere in there I changed the problem in my head to max elements on both left and right, not max on the left and min on the right. I think it's time for bed.

Comment: @Teepeemm Array can have duplicate entries. Not homework and I haven't made any progress I guess. The change of outputs after every selection makes it really hard.

Comment: @cdhowie: Oh, I see, thanks!

Comment: How big can this array be? I think it's obvious how to solve this with dynamic programming in O(n2ⁿ) time and O(2ⁿ) space (where *n* is the array length), but that's not very helpful if the array can have more than, say, 20 or 30 elements.

Comment: @ruakh please share the solution.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: I imagine that if we take the leftmost element, then we merely get the sum of two numbers (that element and the minimum other element), and conversely if we take the rightmost. (And if there's only one element left, then presumably we just get its value when we remove it.) If so, then in some cases it's a better strategy to take the rightmost than the second-rightmost; consider e.g. [2, 1], where we prefer (1+2)+2 rather than (2+1)+1; or [1, 10, 100, 1000, 1], where eliminating the rightmost element first means that we'll thereafter have 1000 as a possible minimum.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: (But I'm not sure if there are any cases where we'd want to take something other than the rightmost or second-to-the-rightmost.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start the bidding with an *O*(*n*2<sup>*n*</sup>) solution . . .

There are a number of ambiguities in your description of the problem, that you have declined to address in comments. None of these ambiguities affects the runtime complexity of this solution, but they do affect implementation details of the solution, so the solution is necessarily somewhat of a sketch.

The solution is as follows:

- Create an array `results` of 2<sup>*n*</sup> integers. Each array index `i` will denote a certain subsequence of the input, and `results[i]` will be the greatest sum that we can achieve *starting with that subsequence*.

  - A convenient way to manage the index-to-subsequence mapping is to represent the first element of the input using the least significant bit (the 1's place), the second element with the 2's place, etc.; so, for example, if our input is `[5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9]`, then the subsequence `5 2 8` would be represented as array index 000111<sub>2</sub> = 7, meaning `results[7]`. (You can also start with the most significant bit — which is probably more intuitive — but then the implementation of that mapping is a little bit less convenient. Up to you.)
- Then proceed in order, from subset #0 (the empty subset) up through subset #2<sup>*n*</sup>−1 (the full input), calculating each array-element by seeing how much we get if we select each possible element and add the corresponding previously-stored values. So, for example, to calculate `results[7]` (for the subsequence `5 2 8`), we select the largest of these values:

  - `results[6]` plus how much we get if we select the `5`
  - `results[5]` plus how much we get if we select the `2`
  - `results[3]` plus how much we get if we select the `8`

  Now, it might *seem* like it should require *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time to compute any given array-element, since there are *n* elements in the input that we could potentially select, and seeing how much we get if we do so requires examining all other elements (to find the maximum among prior elements and the minimum among later elements). However, we can actually do it in just *O*(*n*) time by first making a pass from right to left to record the minimal value that is later than each element of the input, and then proceeding from left to right to try each possible value. (Two *O*(*n*) passes add up to *O*(*n*).)

---

An important caveat: I *suspect* that the correct solution only ever involves, at each step, selecting either the rightmost or second-to-rightmost element. If so, then the above solution calculates many, many more values than an algorithm that took that into account. For example, the result at index 111000<sub>2</sub> is clearly not relevant in that case. But I can't prove this suspicion, so I present the above *O*(*n*2<sup>*n*</sup>) solution as the fastest solution whose correctness I'm certain of.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that the elements are nonnegative absent a suggestion to the contrary.)

Here's an O(n^2)-time algorithm based on ruakh's conjecture that there exists an optimal solution where every selection is from the rightmost two, which I prove below.

The states of the DP are (1) `n`, the number of elements remaining (2) `k`, the index of the rightmost element. We have a recurrence

```
OPT(n, k) = max(max(R(0), ..., R(n - 2)) + R(n - 1) + R(k) + OPT(n - 1, k),
                max(R(0), ..., R(n - 1)) + R(k) + OPT(n - 1, n - 1)),
```

where the first line is when we take the second rightmost element, and the second line is when we take the rightmost. The empty max is zero. The base cases are

```
OPT(1, k) = R(k)
```

for all `k`.

---

Proof: the condition of choosing from the two rightmost elements is equivalent to the restriction that the element at index `i` (counting from zero) can be chosen only when at most `i + 2` elements remain. We show by induction that there exists an optimal solution satisfying this condition for all `i < j` where `j` is the induction variable.

The base case is trivial, since every optimal solution satisfies the vacuous restriction for `j = 0`. In the inductive case, assume that there exists an optimal solution satisfying the restriction for all `i < j`. If `j` is chosen when there are more than `j + 2` elements left, let's consider what happens if we defer that choice until there are exactly `j + 2` elements left. None of the elements left of `j` are chosen in this interval by the inductive hypothesis, so they are irrelevant. Choosing the elements right of `j` can only be at least as profitable, since including `j` cannot decrease the max. Meanwhile, the set of elements left of `j` is the same at both times, and the set of the elements right of `j` is a subset at the later time as compared to the earlier time, so the min does not decrease. We conclude that this deferral does not affect the profitability of the solution.